# Managing different screen sizes using weightsum in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, screen-size, android-layout-weight

This is for all who had a bad time trying to fix the screens for different android  screen sizes.

I tried,

1. Placing views in relativelayout and aligning them according to the relative positions like alignparentright and alignparentbottom. But this couldn't help me when number of views were more.
2. Creating different values files for different screen sizes, like values-w240dp, values-320dp etc. But this can't differentiate between the 4 inch and 5.5 inch mobiles.
3. Giving weightsum to parent layout and giving layout_weight to the views inside. This worked well and the views were getting resized according to screen sizes. But, I had to introduce more linear layouts to group views.

Question is, introducing more linear layouts and weightsum will be costly or not while drawing the screen?  Because we are increasing the viewgroup hierarchy levels unnecessarily.

If costly, what is the best practise to be followed while creating screens for different android screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

For better approach you need to maintain different layout folder for different screen size like below

```
 res/layout/xmlfiles             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
 res/layout-small/xmlfiles       // layout for small screen size
 res/layout-large/xmlfiles       // layout for large screen size
 res/layout-xlarge/xmlfiles      // layout for extra large screen size
 res/layout-xlarge-land/xmlfiles // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

Comment: I tried it. that can be used for differentiating mobiles and tablets. What about a samsung Y and oneplus one? the screen size is 4" and 5.5". both will fall under res/layout-small.

Comment: so you are facing issue with displaying many views in the small layout right?

Comment: It's not just the number of views. I want the views to maintain the same proportion in all the screen sizes. The spacing ratio should be same too.

Comment: if you use weightsum for a view then it will vary in differrent size for different screen, in this case you need to calculate the height and weight values  for different layout screen